# Assigning variables to wlan interfaces with find in a bashscript

Tags: bash, shell, variables, find, aircrack-ng

### Scope

I am working on a bash-script for handling repetitive tasks with putting wlan interfaces on, of, in and out monitor mode and displaying relevant information thru each step.

I started out something like this:

```
wx="wlan${1}"
wxm="${wx}mon"

# $wx
echo "$wx"
echo -n "stop $wxm if up....";airmon-ng stop $wxm  &> /dev/null; echo " done.";
echo -n "bringing down $wx if up....";ifconfig $wx down  &> /dev/null; echo " done.";
echo -n "changing mac to random....";macchanger -r $wx  &> /dev/null; echo " done.";
echo "mac-adresses randomized"
echo -n "bringing up $wx....";ifconfig $wx up&> /dev/null; echo " done.";
echo -n "putting $wx in monitor mode....";airmon-ng start $wx  &> /dev/null; echo " done.";
echo "$wxm successfully put in monitor mode"
wait
```

I tried to different ways to import available wlan-nics and with some help from a friend, ended up with this function using find

```
function setup_if() {
  local wx="${1}"
  local wxm="${wx}mon"

  echo "setting up: $wx..."
  run_cmd airmon-ng stop $wxm &&
    run_cmd ifconfig $wx down &&
    run_cmd macchanger -r $wx &&
    run_cmd ifconfig $wx up &&
    run_cmd airmon-ng start $wx
  wait
}

for interface in $(find /sys/class/net -name 'wlan*'); do
  interface=$(basename ${interface})
  setup_if ${interface}  || echo "FAILED: ${interface} $previous_command"
done
```

### Where I got stuck

Now for the next step i want to print some useful information about the status of the wlans like `cat /sys/class/net/wlan*/address` and `iwconfig |grep  --regexp   wlan`

Finally i would like to export my operating nics to another script for capturing traffic with airodump-ng like `airodump-ng -w /root/pcap/air_capture  -c 1,4,6,8,11 $all_operating_wlans`

### Questions:

1. How do i make unique variables for all detected wlans, like $w1, $w2 etc. I haven't figured out how to make it thru `find /sys/class/net -name 'wlan?mon'`since it is several lines of output that requires several variables.
2. How to make those variables accessible to my other script that will capture packets.
3. Are there better ways to achieve the same results still in a bash-script context?

*This is my first question on stackoverflow, and i'm happy to receive feedback on how my next question could be better!*

Comment: Use http://www.shellcheck.net/. It will highlight the syntax issues with your script to fix.

Comment: From which command are you getting all the detected wlans?

Comment: @Inian That would be "find /sys/class/net -name 'wlan*"

Comment: Can you use arrays in bash for your requirement 1)

Comment: @Inian How would that look?

Comment: Refer my update below

Comment: very good fist Q. Keep posting!

Answer (score 0):

In programming in general it is common to create an array variable when there is a need to store a dynamic collection of values. In Bash 4, it is possible to create an indexed array using [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-mapfile) built-in function:

```
mapfile -t ifaces <<< "$(find /sys/class/net -mindepth 1 -printf '%f\n')"
```

In this example, `mapfile` creates an indexed array `ifaces` by reading lines from a [here string](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html). The content of the here string is built using the [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). Trailing newlines are removed with `-t` option.

Note the use of `-mindepth 1` option. The option excludes the `/sys/class/net` directory itself.

Instead of invoking `basename`, the command uses the `-printf` action (in terms of *find*) with `%f` format specifier:

> `%f`     File's name with any leading directories removed (only the last
>   element).

The `ifaces` variable will be available in the current [scope](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html#SCOPEREF). The array can be traversed as follows:

```
for i in "${ifaces[@]}"
do
  printf "%s\n" "$i"
done
```

Note, `mapfile` was introduced in Bash version 4.

**Process Substitution**

The here string can be replaced with [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
mapfile -t ifaces < <(find /sys/class/net -mindepth 1 -printf '%f\n')
```

It's just a matter of preference.

**Using *mapfile* in a Pipeline**

It is possible to use *mapfile* in a [pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html), but the value of the array will be available only in the scope of the piped command. For example, the following script prints zero:

```
find /sys/class/net -mindepth 1 -printf '%f\n' | mapfile -t ifaces
printf "%d" "${#ifaces[@]}"
```

In order to use the `ifaces` variable within the pipe context, use the [grouping commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html), e.g.:

```
find /sys/class/net -mindepth 1 -printf '%f\n' | {
  mapfile -t ifaces
  printf "%d" "${#ifaces[@]}"
}
```

Obviously, in this case, the scope of the `ifaces` variable will be limited to the group.

**Using Functions**

There is a number of ways to return a value from a function. The simplest way is to set, or modify a global variable:

```
get_ifaces() {
  mapfile -t ifaces < <(find /sys/class/net -mindepth 1 -printf '%f\n')
}
```

But it is a bad practice, since it is possible to overwrite an existing variable unintentionally.

Another way is to write a function that accepts a variable name:

```
get_ifaces() {
  local var_name=$1
  local __ifaces

  mapfile -t __ifaces < <(find /sys/class/net -mindepth 1 -printf '%f\n')

  eval $var_name=\( "${__ifaces[@]}" \)
}

get_ifaces ifaces
```

Ah, I must write this, as I have `eval` in the sample: *warning, warning, warning! You should avoid using `eval` as much as you can, as it may evaluate more than expected* See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead) discussion, for instance. But in this particular example, I don't see any risks of using `eval`.